# Losing mouse focus on map in safari browser

Tags: browser, safari

I am facing problem when I use SAFARI browser for GIS WEB Application. I have select tool in my application to select the features on the map. When i use Safari the point focus is not correct it drags to some other location.

I have tried the same functionality in other browsers like IE, Chrome and Mozilla Firefox. It works perfectly.

Any suggestion what additional needs to be done to make it work in Safari Browser?

Also is Safari recommended for GIS Web Application?

The snapshot1 is of Safari web browser where the mouse focus is lost and it goes out.
[image: snapshot1 - Safari]
Whereas the actual result in other browser is in snapshot2.
[image: snapshot2 - Firefox/IE/Chrome]

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange. You'll need to provide a lot more information for us to help you. What API are you using? What do you mean by "the point focus is not correct it drags to some other location"? Are all of your tests on the same computer? Which "select tool" are you referring to? etc

Comment: Common_SelectFeaturetool.